# How do I use Boost.Asio's spawn (stackful coroutines) so that it only depends on Boost.Context?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, coroutine

In the Asio release notes for Boost 1.80, one finds:

> When targeting C++11 and later, spawn() and basic_yield_context are implemented in terms of Boost.Context directly.

Yay! Now we can remove the dependency on Boost.Coroutine, which is not header-only and needs to be compiled (the dependency on Boost.Context still remains when using `boost::asio::spawn`).

Now my question is: how do I migrate my code so that `boost::asio::spawn` and `boost::asio::basic_yield_context` only depend on Boost.Context?

Answer (score 3):

First off, `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_BOOST_COROUTINE` must be defined to disable all usages of Boost.Coroutine from within Boost.Asio , in order to avoid linker errors.

With `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_BOOST_COROUTINE` defined, you will be forced to pass a [completion token](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html) as the third argument to `boost::asio::spawn`. This completion token must provide a handler with signature `void handler(std::exception_ptr)`, where the `std::exception_ptr` is used to transport exceptions thrown from within the coroutine.

If you simply want exceptions from the coroutine to be discarded (or if it's not possible for exceptions to leak out of the coroutine), you may pass `boost::asio::detached` as the `spawn` completion token. For example:

```cpp
boost::asio::spawn(
    ioctx,
    [](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
        // Do coroutine stuff
    },
    boost::asio::detached
);
```

If you want exceptions to be rethrown by `boost::asio::io_context::run` (as was the old behavior without a completion token), you should pass the following handler (or equivalent) as the completion token:

```cpp
[](std::exception_ptr e) { if (e) std::rethrow_exception(e); }
```

For example:

```cpp
boost::asio::spawn(
    ioctx,
    [](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
        // Do coroutine stuff
        throw std::runtime_error("Oops");
    },
    [](std::exception_ptr e) { if (e) std::rethrow_exception(e); }
);
```

Note that there's currently [a bug](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/1110) in Boost 1.80 where exceptions thrown from coroutines are not captured properly by `boost::asio::spawn`.

Here's a complete example that demonstrates the disabling of Boost.Coroutine, so that it only depends on Boost.Context (and Boost.System):

```cpp
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_BOOST_COROUTINE

#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct propagating_t
{
    constexpr propagating_t() = default;

    void operator()(std::exception_ptr e) const
    {
        if (e) std::rethrow_exception(e);
    }
};

// Our own custom completion token that rethrows exceptions leaked
// from coroutines.
constexpr propagating_t propagating;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioctx;

    boost::asio::spawn(
        ioctx,
        [](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
        {
            std::cout << "Coroutine start" << std::endl;
            throw std::runtime_error("bad");
        },
        propagating
    );

    try
    {
        ioctx.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught unknown exception" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Special thanks to Chris Kohlhoff, the author of Asio, who [helped me understand](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/1111) this usage of `boost::asio::spawn`.

Comment: This is a gold nugget. Thanks for sharing, Emile